# Google map pan controls shown but not working (on mobile)

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zurb-foundation-5

I need to disable `draggable` option for my Google Map and activate pan contols, so user can view map properly on mobile devices. So here is my options:

```
panControl: true,
draggable: false
```

Pan controls are appearing on a map but it seems deactivated. How can I activate it? I also have marker and infoWindow, I don't know if it affects on a pan, so here full map code:

```
function initMap() {

  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( myloc , myloc ),

  options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latLng,
    panControl: true,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    streetViewControl: !1,
    mapTypeControl: !1,
    scrollwheel: !1,
  },

  mapContainer = document.getElementById("map"),

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, options),

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    icon: "/img/map-marker.png"
  }),

  infoWindowContent = '<div class="infowindow">My Info</div>',

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContent
  });

  infoWindow.open(map, marker), google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker)
  }), google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    map.setCenter(latLng)
  });

}
```

Comment: Are you using an javascript mobile development frameworks? e.g. Ionic?

Comment: no, for main template I use Foundation Zurb 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('touchstart', 'div[title*=Mover]', function () {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

Change "Mover" to "Pan" or whatever the Pan command is called on the language you're using on your GMaps script.

Comment: I forgot to metion that this code is for jQuery. But it's easily adaptable to raw Javascript. Also, consider using a "starts with" selector (^), instead of the "anywere" selector (*) I used.